# jQuery.ajax передача множества параметров

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Здравствуйте! Следующий код

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#buttonUpload").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
         url: "uploadContent.php",
         type: "GET",
         cache:true,
         data: {data:$("#textUpload").val()},
         success: function(data){   
           $("#dataUpload").html(data);
         }
       });
     });
  });
  </script>
```

Получает параметр data в id #dataUpload из файла uploadContent.php
У меня вот такая ситуация, необходимо получить несколько параметров uploadContent.php в разные id, но не хочу повторять кучу запросов к BD. Нужно что бы jQuery.ajax выполнила 1 запрос к uploadContent.php и получила все параметры, затем раскидала их по id.

Буду признателен, если кто поможет.
Если дадите статью по работе, буду вдвойне благодарен

Comment: Можно как нибудь вроде  $("#dataUpload").html(data[name]); или что ни будь вроде того. Занести в переменные или массив (((

Answer (score 0):

Ребят всё проблема решена, это делается через JSON

Всем кто заглянул спасибо!

Вот пример

**php**

```
$street = ['lenina' => '306','mira' => '123'];  
echo json_encode($street, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

**jQuery getJSON**

```
$.getJSON("/getHouse.php", {}, function(data){ 
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        $("#target").text(value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Нашёл на просторах интернета))))